# How to restart sshuttle automatically

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am using sshuttle to route some traffic automatically via an ssh jump server.
It works well but in some situations i.e. switching to another Wifi network the connection breaks an i'll have to restart sshuttle manually.

Is it possible to start sshuttle in a way that it restarts automatically whenever a network connection is available again?

We already built a workaround with `until` which retries in a loop until it connects again, but that feels wrong to me?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `systemd` for that, first create a `systemd` service file for `sshutle`

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/sshuttle.service
```

then put this inside ( replace `your_username` and `ssh_jump_server` with the address of your ssh jump server and the other by the network you want to route with `sshutle` )

```
[Unit]
Description=sshuttle tunnel

[Service]
Restart=always
User=<your_username>
Group=<your_username>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshuttle -r <ssh_jump_server> <local_network>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then you can save and reload `systemd` `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` then enable our new `sshuttle` service to start at boot, now the `sshutle` service is automaticaly restarted when it exit and if the network connection is lost, the `sshutle` service will automaticaly restart when the connection is working again.

Comment: Could you explain more about this service?

Comment: the sshuttle service will start at boot with sudo systemctl enable sshuttle. The systemd service will automatically restart sshuttle if it exits or if the network connection is lost. Once the connection is restored, the service will restart as well.

Comment: I don't know why I get error when running this command. Where can I send you my config?

Comment: this is my question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1127706/sshuttle-automate-service-runs-with-error