# sshuttle automate service runs with error

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have written a service as it was given in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1126924/how-to-restart-sshuttle-automatically) question but when I run the service I get only error in status.

service:

GNU nano 6.2                                                     /etc/systemd/system/sshuttle.service
[Unit]
Description=sshuttle tunnel

```
[Service]
Restart=always
User=user
Group=user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshuttle -vr my-ip 0/0 -x my-ip/32 --ssh-cmd 'ssh -i ~/server.pem'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

error I get in status:

```
× sshuttle.service - sshuttle tunnel
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sshuttle.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-02 11:12:09 +0330; 1s ago
    Process: 2142 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshuttle -vr my-ip 0/0 -x my-ip/32 --ssh-cmd ssh -i ~/server.pem (code=exited, status=217/USER)
   Main PID: 2142 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
        CPU: 1ms

Apr 02 11:12:09 mj-virtual-machine systemd[1]: sshuttle.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 02 11:12:09 mj-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Stopped sshuttle tunnel.
Apr 02 11:12:09 mj-virtual-machine systemd[1]: sshuttle.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 02 11:12:09 mj-virtual-machine systemd[1]: sshuttle.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 11:12:09 mj-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start sshuttle tunnel.
```

updated config:

```
[Unit]
Description=sshuttle tunnel

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshuttle -vr ssh-user@ssh-ip 0/0 -x ssh-ip/32 --ssh-cmd 'ssh -i /home/mj/server.pem'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to Saxtheowl

this is my final config and its working fine:

```
[Unit]
Description=sshuttle tunnel

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/sshuttle --dns -vr ssh-user@ssh-ip 0/0 -x ssh-ip/32 --ssh-cmd '/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/ubuntu-user/server.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem in your config like the `~` in `--ssh-cmd` option.

First here is your updated `ExecStart`  `ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshuttle -vr my-ip 0/0 -x my-ip/32 --ssh-cmd 'ssh -i /home/user/server.pem'` then reload your service `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` then we enable and start the service

```
sudo systemctl enable sshuttle.service
sudo systemctl start sshuttle.service
```

edit:

It might be a problem with the user, be sure to use the correct one in the file below:

```
[Unit]
Description=sshuttle tunnel

[Service]
Restart=always
User=<your_username>
Group=<your_groupname>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshuttle -vr ssh-user@ssh-ip 0/0 -x ssh-ip/32 --ssh-cmd 'ssh -i /home/<your_username>/server.pem'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: still have the same error. I have updated the config

Comment: just changed my config, its trying to connect but gives `Host key verification failed.` error

Comment: I have updated my answer maybe it will fix your problem

Comment: When I add user and group, it gives same error but when I don't it says `Host key verification failed.`